Need help on @property in python
I have a class as shown with @property decorator and some methods.
class Alphabet:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    # getting the values
    @property
    def v(self):
        print('Getting value')
        return self._value

    # setting the values
    @v.setter
    def v(self, value):
        print('Setting value to ' + value)
        self._value = value

    # deleting the values
    @v.deleter
    def value(self):
        print('Deleting value')
        del self._value

# passing the value

x = Alphabet('Peter')

print(x.value)

x.value = 'Diesel'

This gives me output as shown:
Getting value
Peter
Setting value to Diesel

How this is possible as the "value" function is not defined to get the value or set the value

It's because you used def value rather than def v when defining the deleter.

Yes, value is defined with a getter and a setter. Your class actually has two properties: one named v, which has a getter and setter, and one named value, which has the same getter and setter as v in addition to a deleter. Take a look at the same class without using decorators:
class Alphabet:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def v(self):
        print('Getting value')
        return self._value

    v = property(v)

    # slight renaming to avoid prematurely overwriting the existing property
    def _v(self, value):
        print('Setting value to ' + value)
        self._value = value
    v = v.setter(_v); del _v

    def value(self):
        print('Deleting value')
        del self._value

    value = v.deleter(value)

v.getter and v.setter do not modify an existing property in-place; they create and return new properties based on v. In the end, you finally decorated a function named value, so that's the name the final property was assigned to.
